# For degenerate perturbation theory, how do we interpret the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\hat V$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, perturbation-theory, matrix-elements

For the eigenvectors that are unmixed by the matrix $\hat V$, the eigenvalues are the energy corrections of this eigenbasis.

However, the eigenbasis tends to always be (as far as I'm aware) a linear combination of unperturbed eigenstates.

I know how to diagonalize $V$ such that for the new bases $\langle\tilde n | V|\tilde k \rangle = 0$ for $k \ne n$ which is the condition to read first-order energy corrections off the diagonal, but in truth, I don't actually know what these eigenvalues are truly, and what these eigenvectors are outside of their mathematcal vagaries.

In my mind, the eigenvectors are a combination of unperturbed eigenstates forming their own state which has a unique energy level that it shares with no other states, which thus have a unique energy correction, but I don't know if it's the 'true' energy level or not. For instance, when I think of energy levels, I think of something like this:

[image]

Or something like this:

[image]

Where do these eigenvectors of $V$ fit into this mix? Are they the 'proper' energy levels (the lines or rings in these images)? How am I meant to interpret these eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $V$?